# how to check file from sdcard selected or not

Tags: android, checkbox, custom-adapter

I am creating an app in which i can fetch files from sdcard and delete it, for deleting files I'm using checkbox but when I'm scrolling it's state gets changed.
How can i check if that file is checked or not? Should i create setters and getters for it?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); 

    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    tv.setText(modelItems.get(position));

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton p1, boolean isChecked)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                if (p1.isChecked())
                {
                    isChecked = true;
                    cb.setChecked(true); 
                }
                else
                {
                    isChecked = false;
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: you need to keep track of every individual item in the list and need to maintain as well

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Add a boolean array with as many items as there are items in the listview. In getVieuw() set the checkbox according to its value. On oncheckbox changed set the value of the specific array item.

Comment: cb.setChecked(checkarray[position]);

Comment: checkarray[position] = isChecked; Use cb tag for position.

Comment: cb.setTag(position); Does that compile?

Comment: How to add boolean array can u give me sample code, i am beginner in android development

Comment: You can also add a boolean ArrayList. You have already an array list. Look at `modelItems`.

Comment: Solved Thanks :)